How to select between Strategy Pattern and Factory Pattern?
When I am going through the design patterns I got confused between the Strategy Pattern and Factory Pattern selection. Even though one is behavioral pattern and later is creational pattern but requirement can be achieved by any one of it. Like single interface has been extended by multiple concrete classes and selection of concrete implementation takes place during run time.
But I am confused in what scenarios which one should be used.
When I tried to understand from AIs available only point highlighted was strategy has more granular control.
Could some one help me understand more practical scenarios and how to choose between them in different scenarios.

Which Factory pattern? There are many.

For the Strategy pattern, imagine a game where you have a playing approach that you've abstracted to the following interface:
interface IPlayingApproach
{
   void Play();
}

To win the game you could take different approaches. For example, you could attack aggressively or proceed cautiously.
These are strategies that can be concrete implementations of the playing approach:
public class AggressiveAttackStrategy : IPlayingApproach
{
   public void Play()
   {
      // Attack aggressively
   }
}

public class ProceedCautiouslyStrategy : IPlayingApproach
{
   public void Play()
   {
      // Proceed cautiously
   }
}



Now, the appropriate strategy can be selected at runtime:
public void Main()
{
   var game = new Game();

   if (playerHasChosenAggressiveApproach)
   {
      game.PlayingApproach = new AggressiveAttackStrategy();      
   }
   else
   {
      game.PlayingApproach = new ProceedCautiouslyStrategy();      
   }

}

This is a really contrived example, but I think it demonstrates the pattern in a simple way.
Ultimately, the Strategy pattern is useful when you have different ways of doing something that can be interchanged without the consumer knowing, or needing to know the details.
